# How can I create new html class with foreach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
   var payload="Online  111:220:9
info  111:220:9
Connected FW build date: May  5 2017 10:56:36  111:222:9
WIFI AP SSID: :), BSSID: Q8:2G:63:14:61:40, SIGNAL: -55  121:250:1
WIFI interface mode: 11N, MAC: 1A:CH:7F:12:03:995  111:220:5
IP: 179.19.199.199, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 179.19.111.259";

     var arr = payload.split(/\n/g);
     var ss="koikpay";
     var sa=0;
     arr.forEach(function(entry) {
         sa++;
         ss=ss+sa;
         document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="'+ss+'">' + entry + '</span>'
    });
```

**I would like to make new html class for each line of array.**

This example sadly dosen't work!

Can I archive this with forEach or I have to use an loop?

Comment: The code looks all cool, but I do not think your code has any new line characters in it.

Comment: Your code does work, though? See https://jsfiddle.net/peskjjb0/

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues. Firstly, when a string literal contains line breaks you need to use the backtick (`` ` ``) character to delimit the string.

The second issue is that you're updating `ss` on each loop, so the value will become `foo1`, `foo12`, `foo123`... You need to amend the value within scope of the loop only. Better still, you can use the `index` parameter provided to the `forEach()` handler. Try this:

```js
var payload = `Online  111:220:9
info  111:220:9
Connected FW build date: May  5 2017 10:56:36  111:222:9
WIFI AP SSID: :), BSSID: Q8:2G:63:14:61:40, SIGNAL: -55  121:250:1
WIFI interface mode: 11N, MAC: 1A:CH:7F:12:03:995  111:220:5
IP: 179.19.199.199, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 179.19.111.259`;

var arr = payload.split(/\n/g);
var ss = "koikpay";

arr.forEach(function(entry, sa) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="' + ss + sa + '">' + entry + '</span>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new class in every iteration like so:

```js
var arr =  ["cat","dog","ball","bat"] 
var ss = "class_prefix_";
var sa = 0;
arr.forEach(function(entry)
{
         sa++;
         ss=ss+sa;
         document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += '<span class="'+ss+'">' + entry + '</span><br/>'
    });
```

```html
<div id="data">

</div>
```

Here arr will be your array.

Answer (score 0):

Use template literals to save your text like this:

```js
var payload=`Online  111:220:9
info  111:220:9
Connected FW build date: May  5 2017 10:56:36  111:222:9
WIFI AP SSID: :), BSSID: Q8:2G:63:14:61:40, SIGNAL: -55  121:250:1
WIFI interface mode: 11N, MAC: 1A:CH:7F:12:03:995  111:220:5
IP: 179.19.199.199, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 179.19.111.259`;

     var arr = payload.split(/\n/g);
     var ss="koikpay";
     var sa=0;
     arr.forEach(function(entry) {
         sa++;
         var className = ss+sa;
         document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="'+className+'">' + entry + '</span>'
    });
```

Notice the backticks `for the string above.
I also corrected an error you had in the loop where you were updating the`ss` variable leading to your class naming becoming concatenated in the wrong manner.

Comment: I would use the backticks, BUT I was showing the payload as an example, since the actual payload is an mqtt variable

Comment: @Somepub You also had an error in the class name. Also corrected that. Please check the updated answer. Other than that, I don't think you have any other error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const payload = `Online  111:220:9
info 111: 220: 9
Connected FW build date: May 5 2017 10: 56: 36 111: 222: 9
WIFI AP SSID:: ), BSSID: Q8: 2 G: 63: 14: 61: 40, SIGNAL: -55 121: 250: 1
WIFI interface mode: 11 N, MAC: 1 A: CH: 7 F: 12: 03: 995 111: 220: 5
IP: 179.19 .199 .199, MASK: 255.255 .255 .0, GW: 179.19 .111 .259`;

const arr = payload.split(/\n/g);
const className = "koikpay";

arr.forEach((entry, index) => {
  document.body.innerHTML += `<div class="${className}-${index}">${entry}</div>`
});
```

```css
.koikpay-0 {
  color: limegreen;
}

.koikpay-1 {
  color: red;
}

.koikpay-2 {
  color: green;
}

.koikpay-3 {
  color: blue;
}

.koikpay-4 {
  color: gold;
}

.koikpay-5 {
  color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ES6` solves this particular case using the **``** ([Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) notation for multi line strings. Other ways are to have `\n` in your string to indicate a new line or if its just the same string but editor's width is smaller you can use the `\` to append multiple lines in the same string. may like to see the snippets -

```js
/*ES6*/
var payload1=`Online  111:220:9
info  111:220:9
Connected FW build date: May  5 2017 10:56:36  111:222:9
WIFI AP SSID: :), BSSID: Q8:2G:63:14:61:40, SIGNAL: -55  121:250:1
WIFI interface mode: 11N, MAC: 1A:CH:7F:12:03:995  111:220:5
IP: 179.19.199.199, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 179.19.111.259`;

     var arr = payload1.split(/\n/g);
     var ss="koikpay";
     var sa=0;
     arr.forEach(function(entry) {
         sa++;
         ss=ss+sa;
         document.body.innerHTML += '<div class='+ss+'>' + entry + '</div>'
    });
    
    
 /*Simple New Liner notation*/   
 var payload2="Online  111:220:9 \n" + 
             "info  111:220:9";


     var arr = payload2.split(/\n/g);
     var ss="koikpay";
     var sa=0;
     arr.forEach(function(entry) {
         sa++;
         ss=ss+sa;
         document.body.innerHTML += '<div class='+ss+'>' + entry + '</div>'
    });
    
    /*String in multiple lines*/
    var payload3="Online  111:220:9 \
info  111:220:9 \
Connected FW build date: May  5 2017 10:56:36  111:222:9 \
WIFI AP SSID: :), BSSID: Q8:2G:63:14:61:40, SIGNAL: -55  121:250:1 \
WIFI interface mode: 11N, MAC: 1A:CH:7F:12:03:995  111:220:5 \
IP: 179.19.199.199, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 179.19.111.259";

     var arr = payload3.split(/\n/g);
     var ss="koikpay";
     var sa=0;
     arr.forEach(function(entry) {
         sa++;
         ss=ss+sa;
         document.body.innerHTML += '<div class='+ss+'>' + entry + '</div>'
    });
```

```css
.koikpay1{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Also note that the index is already available in the `.forEach(entry, index, array)` so the `var sa` is not necessary to track the index.